# error : The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default

Tags: python, django, post

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Django-Rest framework, estoy trabajando con la clase User que ofrece el propio Django-rest, ademas de esto para manejar información adicional, estoy usando una clase `UserInformation`, la cual tiene una foreign key a User, el problema es que cuando intento crear un UserInformation a través de un `post` me sale el siguiente error:

> The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by
>   default. Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer
>   `UsuariosGeneral.serializers.UserInformationSerializer`, or set
>   `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

models.py:

```
class UserInformation(models.Model):
    numberid = models.CharField(db_column='NumberId', primary_key=True, max_length=15)  # Field name made lowercase.
    celphone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    instagram = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    facebook = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    google = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    type_id_idtype = models.ForeignKey(TypeId, models.DO_NOTHING)
    auth_user = models.OneToOneField(User, models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    legal = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'user_information'
       unique_together = (('numberid', 'type_id_idtype', 'auth_user'),)
```

serializers.py:

```
class TypeIdSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = models.TypeId
      fields = ('idtype_id',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   groups = GroupSerializer(many = True,)

   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'is_staff','groups',)
      extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

   def create(self, validated_data):
      user = User(
          email=validated_data['email'],
          username=validated_data['username'],
          is_superuser = validated_data['is_superuser']
       )
      user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
      user.save()
      return user

class UserInformationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   type_id_idtype = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = False,read_only = False,queryset= TypeId.objects.all(),)
   auth_user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)
   class Meta:
      model = models.UserInformation
      fields =('numberid','celphone','instagram','facebook','google','type_id_idtype','auth_user',)
```

views.py:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
   serializer_class = UserSerializer
   authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
   permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)
   filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
   search_fields = ('username', 'email',)

class UserInformationView(APIView):

  def get(self,request):
      try:
        information = models.UserInformation.objects.get(auth_user=request.user.id)
        return Response({"numberid": information.numberid,"celphone": information.celphone,"instagram": information.instagram,"facebook": information.facebook,"google":information.google,"type_id_idtype":information.type_id_idtype.idtype_id,"created_on":information.created_on})
      except:
        Error = "Error 404, usuario no encontrado"
        return Response({"error": Error})

  def post(self,request):
     serializer = serializers.UserInformationSerializer(data = request.data)
     if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
     else:
         Error = "Error 400 Bad request"
         return Response({"error": Error})
```